# XSLT: Select nodes based on an attribute value and a parameter value

Tags: xslt

I would like to declare a variable and select nodes based on an attribute value and a parameter value.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <group>
    <item show='false'>item1</item>
    <item show='true'>item2</item>
    <item show='false'>item3</item>
  </group>
  <group>
    <item show='false'>item4</item>
    <item show='true'>item5</item>
  </group>
</catalog>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
    <xsl:call-template name="atemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="aparam" select="true"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <br/>
    <xsl:call-template name="atemplate"/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="atemplate">
    <xsl:param name="aparam" select="'false'"/>
    <xsl:variable 
      name="items"
      select=".//item[$aparam = 'false' or ($aparam = 'true' and @show = 'true')]"
    />

    <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="$items">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result:

item1
item2
item3
item4
item5

The wanted result:

item2
item5

item1
item2
item3
item4
item5

Comment: Can you show us minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, wanted result and current result or error when it "doesn't work"? Note that boolean values in XPath/XSLT are `true()` and `false()` so a parameter would be `<xsl:param name="aparam" select="false()"/>` and a check in a boolean context then `$aparam`.

Comment: Thank you, @MartinHonnen. The problem was that the parameter was passed as select="true"

Comment: So you edited the xslt in your question and now it works okay? If yes, try to undo your editing and correct this in new answer to this quetsion.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it works as expected, thank you @MartinHonnen for your comment:

```
<xsl:call-template name="atemplate">
    <!-- The problem was in that the parameter passed as select="true"-->
    <xsl:with-param name="aparam" select="'true'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```